# Is there an open postgreSQL dump for geospatial data?

Tags: geospatial

something along these lines:
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Sample_Databases

the open streetmap data is huge. I am looking for a small to medium dataset that is quick to download but diverse enough to play with and learn.

Comment: You can just select a small area on www.openstreetmap.org .

Comment: CartoDB has tons of user datasets to download (as shapefiles, geojson, csv, etc.) for exploration: https://cartodb.com/explore